# Tilde at end of URL?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, url

My co-worker ran a backup of our SP 2010 Enterprise test environment and one of the files that failed to backup was `servername/SF/projects/walt/Images Images1/~Views`. I only have access to files from the web and SharePoint Designer and can't find where this path points to. Does anyone know what `~Views` means?

Comment: what is the file type, imgae /document?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I'm not sure what the file type is because the URL ends with just `~Views` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this before, not sure how the page was created though it is working when I am navigating to the site with tilde "~". This seems to be just any other normal character that is used in the URL.

Please see additional discussions here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252471/what-is-the-use-of-tilde-in-url